# How to use custom domain in CloudFront distribution?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-cloudfront

I recently deployed an application to the S3 service. As this S3 service does not enable HTTPS, I decided to use the CloudFront service that allows the use of HTTPS. However, I don't want my users to access the cloudfront domain.
I have a domain registered with Hostinger, I would like the content delivered by cloudfront to be rendered when entering that domain. For this, I would say that I need the machine's IP to add to the A record, I did this with an EC2 instance adding the IPv4 value and I was successful, however, I don't know if it is possible to obtain an IP address with the CloudFront service. I don't intend to use EC2 since I already have an instance and having another would be costly for those with the free plan.

Is there any way to get the IP of a CloudFront distribution such that I put it in the domain's A record? If not then what can I do?

I simply have a domain registered with Hostinger. I want to point to a certain IP in the A record, but CloudFront doesn't seem to have a fixed IP...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure your DNS provider does not provide support for the ANAME records. It's not a standard type, so not all providers support it.
If your provider has such support, then you should configure the ANAME record to redirect traffic to your distribution domain.

Cloudfront is a CDN, which means it has a different IP address in each edge location (you can think about edge location as a separate IP for each country or a geo-region). If you will use only one IP, you'll not use the geo-replication feature of Cloudfront, because all requests will be facing always the same edge location. Instead, I would suggest you one of the options:

1. Move DNS Zone to Route53
2. Create a new DNS Zone in Route53, and redirect your current DNS provider with NS records

After, you'll be able to create an ALIAS record in Route53. ALIAS records are Route53 implementation of ANAME records.

Comment: I'm sorry to ask, but is what you're saying in points 1 and 2 similar to what's said in this AWS video? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qpwWh0RjrJc
And after creating an Alias record, can I inform the cloudfront distribution link, so that my application is displayed when entering the domain? That's something new to me, I hope you understand

Comment: @Bruna the video shows exactly what I wrote.
Regarding your second question - you need to set up ALIAS in the CloudFront distribution settings. In order to support HTTPS, you need also to create a certificate for your domain in AWS ACM and select it in the CloudFront distribution settings.

Comment: I'm going to try it